# How to verify no interactions on RxJava2 Observable using Mockito

Tags: android, testing, mockito, rx-java2

Observable is final class, so we can't create mocks for it to verify or capture any interactions performed on it.

And Observable's `test()`, TestSubscriber also does not provide any such interaction assertion techinque

I have created a generic method for checking cached data before loading from network

```
/**
 * General parametrized method for loading data from service while checking connection
 * and respecting reload state
 */
private <T> Observable<T> getData(Observable<T> dataSource, String key, boolean reload) {
    T cachedData = (T) cacheModel.getValue(key);

    // Do not use cache if reloading
    if(!reload && cachedData != null)
        return Observable.just(cachedData);

    if(!utilModel.isConnected()) {
        return Observable.error(new Throwable(Constants.NO_NETWORK));
    }

    return dataSource
        .doOnNext(data -> cacheModel.saveObject(key, data))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

And using it as follows:

```
@Override
public Observable<User> getOrganiser(boolean reload) {
    return getData(eventService.getUser(authorization), ORGANIZER, reload);
}
```

Before, I was not even calling `eventService.getUser(...)` to get the observable, so I could test if it was never being called, but now, as I have to pass it to the template method, I need to call it but verify if cache is present, it is never interacted with.

This is my previous test, which is obviously failing now

```
@Test
public void shouldLoadOrganizerFromCache() {
    // Clear cache
    objectCache.clear();

    User user = new User();
    objectCache.saveObject(RetrofitEventRepository.ORGANIZER, user);

    // No force reload ensures use of cache
    Observable<User> userObservable = retrofitEventModel.getOrganiser(false);

    userObservable.test().assertNoErrors();
    userObservable.test().assertValue(user);

    verify(eventService, never()).getUser(auth);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Observable you want to test is something like this:

```
Observable<User> userObservable = getData(eventService.getUser(authorization));
```

while you can't use directly `test()` method or subscribing with `TestObserver`, as you hand the input `Observable` to a different entity. you can use `Observable` side effect methods to verify almost any interaction with the `Observable`.
for instance in your case, you can use `doOnSubscribe` and raise a flag if it was called (indicates the service method was called while it shouldn't as cache should be invoked):

```
final boolean[] serviceCalled = new boolean[1];
Observable<User> userServiceObservable = eventService.getUser(authorization)
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> serviceCalled[0] = true);

Observable<User> userObservable = getData(userServiceObservable, ORGANIZER, reload);
userObservable.test()
        .assertNoErrors()
        .assertValue(user)
        .awaitTerminalEvent();
Assert.assertEquals(false, serviceCalled[0]);
```

BTW, your cache method might not work as expected as your'e testing the cache at getting the `Observable` and not when subscribing, so cache state can be different at subscribe time. also multiple calls can happen simultaneously resulting with multiple calls to server and updating the cache, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240800/3903847) my suggestion of cache using `Observable.defer()`.

Comment: It becomes rigid over time to test the interactions which the subscriber will make and as I am just testing the repository and not the repository with presenter, the observable returned will never actually be subscribed, so I can't test for that

And thanks for your cache implementation. I was looking for just that but couldn't find it. I knew there would be a more reactive way of doing it.